# Drag and drop from one form to anywhere in another form

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, delphi-xe2, drag

I have an MDI form application with two Forms. The first one has a StringGrid, the second form has a lot of Edit controls and a few buttons.

I need to drag from the grid and drop on the second Form and update one Edit with the value of the selected cell in the StringGrid in the first Form.

This is pretty easy to do if I know in advance on which control the user will release the mouse left button as I can set the OnDragDrop event of that specific control. But I do not want to code multiple OnDragDrop events for each and every control on the second Form.

How to intercept a form-wide message to intercept the drop operation on ANY control?

Comment: You don't need to code separate `OnDragOver/OnDragDrop` events. Set all receiving controls's `OnDragOver/OnDragDrop` events to point to one common handler. The `Sender` parameter tells you which control is about to receive the drop and the `Source` parameter tells you - well, the source.

Comment: yes i know but i still need to assign manually the same handler to the onDragDrop event of every component. A possible solution could be enumerate all components on the form and programmaticaly assign that handler to each and every component... but i keep getting an invalid typecast error if i try that

Comment: @user1566931  Enumerate controls, not components

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a custom [DragObject](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TDragControlObjectEx) in the [`OnStartDrag`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnStartDrag) event of the StringGrid:

```
{ TMyDragObject }

type
  TMyDragObject = class(TDragControlObjectEx)
  protected
    DragText: String;
    procedure Finished(Target: TObject; X, Y: Integer; Accepted: Boolean); override;
    function GetDragCursor(Accepted: Boolean; X, Y: Integer): TCursor; override;
  end;

procedure TMyDragObject.Finished(Target: TObject; X, Y: Integer; Accepted: Boolean);
begin
  if Target is TCustomEdit then
    TCustomEdit(Target).SelText := DragText;
  inherited;
end;

function TMyDragObject.GetDragCursor(Accepted: Boolean; X, Y: Integer): TCursor;
begin
  if TObject(DragTarget) is TCustomEdit then
    Result := crDrag
  else
    Result := inherited GetDragCursor(Accepted, X, Y);
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.StringGrid1StartDrag(Sender: TObject; var DragObject: TDragObject);
begin
  DragObject := TMyDragObject.Create(StringGrid1);
  TMyDragObject(DragObject).DragText := StringGrid1.Cells[StringGrid1.Col,
    StringGrid1.Row];
end;
```